# How to search for a pattern (MRS.) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping, pattern-matching

How to search for a pattern (MRS.) in SQL Server 2008? I have used escape operator  and `[]`, but it was not working

Comment: Provide us with a sample data, and the desired result?

Comment: `like '%(MRS.)%'` ?

Comment: How can I search Mr. Jackson

Comment: How can I search Mr. Jackson

Answer (score 0):

use next wild card, and if the answer is not accurate, provide us with sample and desired data.

```
ColumnName like '%(MRS.)%'
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table MyTable (id int  , name nvarchar(200))

insert into MyTable values (1 , 'aaaaaa (MRS.)bbbbb')
insert into MyTable values (2 , '1111 (MRS.)2222')
insert into MyTable values (3 , 'qqqqqqqq')
insert into MyTable values (4 , 'ffffffffff')

select * from MyTable
where name like '%(MRS.)%'
```

Result:-

```
id  name
1   aaaaaa (MRS.)bbbbb
2   1111 (MRS.)2222
```

Comment: How can I search Mr. Jackson

Comment: @user3500529 via `ColumnName like '%MRS.%'
`